# Map several tables to single entity with JPA

Tags: jpa, nested-sets

I've to put hierarchical classifier to a database. The problem with this classifier that

1. it contains several GBs of data and ~20 millions of the records
2. it has 'sparse' structure, like when level 7 subtree connects directly to level 2 one
3. levels and level groups may have different sets of the attributes
4. I need to have fast read queries for subtrees and parents (and no writes at all)

Initially, I've tried to use a single table with nested sets and all possible columns, but it does not work well.

Now I trying to find a way to split all this data across the different tables and keep level-specific data within the lazy-fetched entities. But, at the same time, I'd like to have a single entity (or Map) to work with.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Send the structure for the database.

Comment: it is like below, up to 99 levels, more than 30 different columns.
    --- Table Classifier
    -- PK refCode
    -- left
    -- right
    -- parent
    -- root
    -- level
    -- title

    --- Table level1
    -- FK refCode
    -- status
    -- pCode
    -- orgCode
    -- type
    -- contacts

    --- Table level2
    -- FK refCode
    -- pCode
    -- type
    -- index

    --- Table level7
    -- FK refCode
    -- FK xLink
    -- index